# Condiciones para que un servicio sea REST (Teoría)

Tags: java, rest, arquitectura, teoría

Hace tiempo recibí un email de una consultora que nos dijo que no tenemos realmente servicios web REST sino simplemente servicios web HTTP puesto que no usamos Jersey ni ningún *framework* para REST en Java y nuestros servicios en algunos casos necesitan *cookies* con lo que ya no serian "*stateless*". Tampoco podemos generar el archivo WADL.

¿Cuales son las condiciones para que un servicio sea considerado REST o RESTful?

Wikipedia:

> ...en la actualidad se usa en el sentido más amplio para describir
>   cualquier interfaz entre sistemas que utilice directamente HTTP para
>   obtener datos o indicar la ejecución de operaciones sobre los datos,
>   en cualquier formato (XML, JSON, etc) sin las abstracciones
>   adicionales de los protocolos basados en patrones de intercambio de
>   mensajes, como por ejemplo SOAP...

- Si es sólo cuestón de opinión cierro el POST, gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El hecho de no utilizar Jersey o Resteasey no significa que no se está utilizando REST, éstos simplemente son implementaciones de la especificación JAX-RS para Java.

Cláramente se puede crear una aplicación RESTful sin ésta especificación/implementación pero cuál sería el fin ? Para qué recrear la rueda?

> Unlike SOAP-based web services, there is no "official" standard for
>   RESTful web APIs.[18] This is because REST is an architectural style,
>   while SOAP is a protocol. REST is not a standard in itself, but
>   RESTful implementations make use of standards, such as HTTP, URI,
>   JSON, and XML.

Es decir, que RESTful no es un **standard oficial** sino que utiliza otros standards y con tal que cumpla en lo mayor posible estas [6 reglas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) en mi opinión, se está utilizando REST.

El problema surge ya con la utilización de Cookies y otras cosas,debido a que una de las reglas es que deba ser stateless, i.e.:

> No debe guardar información del cliente del lado del servidor.

Por lo que depende de cómo se utilizan las cookies pero éste es un [debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication) largo en donde hay varias formas de implementar seguridad en un servicio web REST.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la consultora se tiro a la piscina. Hasta donde yo se (que puedo estar equivocado y la consultora en lo cierto), REST establece una interface de comunicación sin estado basándose en el protocolo HTTP. La tecnología usada por detrás para hacerlo es indiferente (jersey, spring,....). Si utilizáis comandos http, devolvéis códigos http, y cumplís el resto de requisitos (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transferencia_de_Estado_Representacional) para mi si que son servicios REST.

El tema de las cookies sería un caso aparte, pero yo no soy tan "Restafari" como para decir que no es REST si lo usáis ;)